# Is it good practice to reference services in html templates in Angular 2?

Tags: templates, service, angular, state, observable

As the question states, is there any downside in referencing the service directly in the template as such :

```
 [disabled]="stateService.selectedClient == null || stateService.currentStep == 1"
```

In my opinion this doesn't seem like good practice and I'd much rather keep a "selectedClient" object in whatever component needs to use it. How can I get the state and store it into local variables, while observing the changes:

example: I want to move from step1 to step2 by changing "currentStep" in the "stateService", however I want the component that keeps "currentStep" ALSO as a local variable to reflect the change in the state?

Comment: I'd avoid it. What if the component access a value multiple times ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is it good practice to reference services in html templates in Angular
>   2?

I'd generally avoid it. It seems to bring more chaos than good.

Cons:

- Coming from OOP background, this approach looks like it breaks the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), but more importantly,
- It's no longer MVC, where your controller (Angular2's `Component`) acts like a mediator between the view and the services.
- Like [Ced](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4299560/ced) said, what if a call to a service's member is costly and we need to refer to it multiple times in the view?
- At the moment my editor of choice (VS Code) does not fully support Angular2 templates; referencing too many things outside of its own `Component`'s scope in a `template` makes refactoring not fun anymore.

Pros:

- Sometimes it looks more elegant (because it saves you 2 lines of code), but trust me, it's not.

> How can I get the state and store it into local variables, while
>   observing the changes

[Madhu Ranjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3508656/madhu-ranjan) has a good answer to this. I'll just try to make it more complete here for your particular example:

In your `StateService`, define:

```
currentStep : Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();
selectedClient: Subject<Client> = new Subject<Client>();

changeStep(nextStep: number){          
  this.currentStep.next(nextStep);
}

selectClient(client: Client) {
  this.selectedClient.next(client);
}
```

In your `Component`:

```
currentStep: number;

constructor(stateService : StateService){
  stateService.currentStep.combineLatest(
    stateService.selectedClient, 
    (currStep, client) => {
      if (client == null) {
        // I'm assuming you are not showing any step here, replace it with your logic
        return -1; 
      }
      return currStep;
    })
  .subscribe(val => {
    this.currentStep = val;
  });
}
```

Comment: Contrary to the popular belief, angular advises on binding to your services directly from your templates. Read here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#bind-to-the-messageservice Then again, I myself do not like that and it feels like an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You may try below,

**stateService**

```
 currentStep : Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();

 somestepChangeMethod(){          
    this.currentStep.next(<set step here to depending on your logic>);
 }
```

**component**

```
 // use this in template
 currentStep: number;

 constructor(stateService : stateServiceClass){
    stateService.currentStep.subscribe(val => {
       this.currentStep = val;
    });
 }
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 2):

It is probably not a good idea to expose your subject inside of your state service. Something like this would be better.

**StateService**

```
private currentStep: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();

changeStep(value: number) {
  this.currentStep.next(value);
}

get theCurrentStep(): Observable<number> {
  this.currentStep.asObservable();
}
```

**Component**

```
currentStep: number;

constructor(private stateService: StateService) {
  this.currentStep = this.stateService.theCurrentStep;
}
```

**Template**

```
[disabled]="(currentStep | async) == 1" // Not sure if this part would work
```